# "ab" preposition with Akkusative?

Tags: preposition, dative, accusative

"**Ab**" is considered *Dative* preposition, but in Duden it is said it sometimes can come with *Akkusative*: "Bei artikellosen Substantiven mit adj. Attribut gelegtl. auch mit Akk.", what does exactly this mean?

Does it mean when noun is without article, after "**ab**" case can be Akkusative?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to the "Zweifelsfallduden" ([Duden Band 9](https://www.duden.de/Shop/Das-Worterbuch-der-sprachlichen-Zweifelsfalle), Das Wörterbuch der sprachlichen Zweifelsfälle), the preposition *ab* in conjunction with **locations** always requires the **dative**:

> ab unserem Werk
>
> ab welcher Station?
>
> ab allen deutschen Flughäfen

In all other use cases, *ab* can also be used with the **accusative**:

> ab erstem Mai / ab ersten Mai
>
> ab letztem Montag / ab letzten Montag
>
> ab vier Nächten / ab vier Nächte
>
> Ab 50 Exemplaren / Ab 50 Exemplare wird Rabatt gewährt.
>
> Dieser Film ist jugendfrei ab zwölf Jahren / ab zwölf Jahre.

However, if a **determiner** is involved, again only the **dative** is possible:

> ab dem 15. Mai
>
> ab der dritten Runde
>
> ab meinem 18. Lebensjahr

Answer (score 3):

The abbreviation *gelegtl.* is for *gelegentlich* – **sometimes**.

> Sie ist ab nächster Woche in Urlaub. *(Dativ)*
>
> Sie ist ab der nächsten Woche in Urlaub. *(Dativ)*
>
> Sie ist ab nächste Woche in Urlaub. *(Akkusativ)*

I account this more to general sloppyness than being a real *Akkusativ*. On word ends, -er is spoken *Tiefschwa* and -e is spoken *Schwa*, there isn't that much difference.

Answer (score 3):

I mistrust the analysis of Duden here.

It's true that you can say "ab nächsten Donnerstag", which is definitely an accusative. But I don't think it's the "ab" which triggers the accusative here. Rather, "ab" can be used with any temporal expression: "ab morgen", "ab 10:00 Uhr", "ab Montag". And absolute temporal expressions use the accusative even without a preposition: "Nächsten Montag bin ich im Urlaub".

So the case is not due to "ab", but due to the use of a noun phrase as a temporal expression. (Note that "bis" and "von...an" exhibit the exact same behaviour with time expressions.)